# How to fill an Ellipses?

Tags: plotting, graphics, filling

I am very new to Mathematica and I am plotting a standard deviation and represent it in ellipses form. But I am having a trouble filling it in with a color instead of showing a dot in the center.

Center dot represents the average of data point so it is just a center mark, which is not necessary.

```
OverallSD = {{0.037, 0.75} \[PlusMinus] {{.008}, {.09}}}
OverallSDPlot = ListPlot[{OverallSD}, IntervalMarkers -> "Ellipses",PlotStyle -> {LightRed}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Tried using Ellipsoid but I don't know how to implement it in the equation.
This is where I am stuck and I can't move on..

Any help would be much appreciated..
Thank you.

Comment: `Disk[{0, 0}, {4, 3}] // Graphics` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work and allows you to carry on using the `IntervalMarkers`, but works by modifying the plot internals, so be careful if you add any other markers that might be based on `BezierCurve` internally:

```
OverallSD = {{0.037, 0.75} \[PlusMinus] {{.008}, {.09}}}
OverallSDPlot = ListPlot[{OverallSD}, IntervalMarkers -> "Ellipses",
   IntervalMarkersStyle -> 
    Directive[FaceForm[Pink], Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[Red]], 
   PlotStyle -> {LightRed}, PlotRange -> All] /. 
  BezierCurve[x_] :> FilledCurve[BezierCurve[x]]
```

[image: ellipse]

Comment: This worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[Green], EdgeForm[Red], Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {2, 1 }]}]
```

[image]